# Grouping files by ignoring file extension in gulp

Tags: gulp

Assuming the following list of files

```
file1.csv
file2.csv
file2.js
```

a standard gulp task may look like this

```
gulp.task( 'exampleTask', function() {
  return gulp.src([ '*.json', '*.csv', '*.js' ])
    .pipe( gulpModule() )
    .pipe( gulp.dest( '/dest/' ) );
});
```

Using that setup each of the three files will get piped through `gulpModule()`.

My requirement, however, is slightly different: If the file extension is not `.js` and the same filename exists just with a `.js` extension, then do not pipe the current file along.

So in the above example, only the following files would get piped through `gulpModule()`:

```
file1.csv
file2.js
```

Any idea how to achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should be able to do this with a simple plugin, as demonstrated below.

1. In the plugin, inspect your file name and run your business rules.
2. If the file meets the parameters, pass it along with `this.push()`

`var through = require('through2');`
`var path = require("path");`

```
gulp.task( 'exampleTask', function() {
      return gulp.src([ '*.json', '*.csv', '*.js' ])
        .pipe(exclude())
        .pipe( gulpModule() )
        .pipe( gulp.dest( '/dest/' ) );
    });


    var exclude = function() {

        return through.obj(function (file, enc, callback) {     

                var ext = path.extname(file.path),
                  filePath = file.path.substring(0,file.path.length-ext.length);

                if (ext!=".js" &&  !fs.existsSync(filePath + ".js") ) 
                {
                    //push it, otherwise ignore it.
                    this.push(file);
                }     

            return callback();
        });

    };
```

Comment: how to add file with extension only like .htaccess file in gulp